# Get ID value from draggable element

Tags: javascript, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I've the following code:

```
$( init );

function init() {

 $(".Arrastrable").draggable({

stop: function(event, ui) {

    var pos = $(this).position();

    $("div#stop").text("Pos:  "+ pos.left + ", " + pos.top);
    }

});

}
```

In the HTML I've the following:

```
<body>

<div id="contenido" style="height: 400px;">
<form name="Registro" action="Guardar" method="post" id="Registro">
    <table
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="Arrastrable">
                    <img src="./css/Imagenes/mesa.png" id="mesa1"></img>
                </div>
                <div class="Arrastrable">
                    <img src="./css/Imagenes/mesa.png" id="mesa2"></img>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</form>
</body>
```

I need to get the ID value of the actual draggable element,I've tried using `$(ui.item).attr("id")` but it didn't work. I don't know if I have to add another method or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember exactly how the property is called, I'll look it up in jsfiddle and edit here, but you could do this:

```
 $(".Arrastrable").draggable({

stop: function(event, ui) {    
    var pos = $(this).position();

     console.dir(event); 
        console.dir(ui);

    $("div#stop").text("Pos:  "+ pos.left + ", " + pos.top);
    }

});
```

and check the properties in Google web developer tools or firebug.

OK, checking [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nicosunshine/Rrp3J/), you can see in the console the properties of the event and the ui object, and the property you're looking for in `event.target.firstChild.id` (or use jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ui.item` for `.draggable()`.  The element being dragged is the `div.Arrastrable`, which has no id in your code.  If you want the id for the image being dragged use `$("img", this).attr("id")`.

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3dcSX/

```
$(init);
function init() {
    $(".Arrastrable").draggable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var imgId = $("img", this).attr("id");
            var pos = $(this).position();
            $("#stop").text("Pos:  " + pos.left + ", " + pos.top + ". Id: " + imgId);
        }
    });
}
```